# How can I use yolov5 or yolov7 without PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, raspberry-pi, yolov5, yolov7

I got Raspberry Pi 3B+ 32 bit. I can't install PyTorch since it asks for 64 bit. Is there a way to use yolov5 or yolov7 without PyTorch or just install PyTorch somehow?

I tried to pip install requirements but got an error followed by "Couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement torch."

Comment: using Google `pytorch raspberry pi 3 32 bit` I found repo [pytorch-rpi](https://github.com/ljk53/pytorch-rpi)  on GItHub and there is some info about `Raspberry 3 (32-bit)` but I never tested it. I found also [PyTorch Installation for Raspberry Pi 3B](https://gist.github.com/awwong1/8728f03cef08e057bd9ae1375a97d798) which explains how to install from source code.

Comment: im not sure about 1st one, and there are several comments about 32bits on 2nd one, not sure.

Comment: I have `Raspberry 3 (32-bit)` but I don't space on sd card to download code from `pytorch-rpi` and test it. I can't help you at this moment.

Comment: thank you anyways